# Use Custom Field as Timezone Parameter in Date Field

Tags: custom-fields, parse-order

I have a custom field where the publisher can choose what time zone they want the entry date to display as, but I'm having trouble when trying to use it in the template:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel='events'
}
    {entry_date format='%g:%i%a %T' timezone='{events_tz}'}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Since both tags are parsed at the same time, the `{events_tz}` field doesn't get parsed in time to be applied as a parameter to the date field.

How would I accomplish this? I'm willing to use Stash, if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm inferring correctly, there are events in multiple time zones and they want each to show in the time that is local to the location of the event. If so, I think what you want is [Fixed](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/custom_fields_edit.html#field-type) instead of Localized, and just output the time zone next to the date.

If you must use entry date, which will always be localized, you could create a simple plugin that accepts the UTC timestamp and the timezone and return a formatted date, e.g.:

```
{exp:your_date_plugin timestamp='{entry_date}' timezone='{events_tz}'}
```

Comment: I'm not using a date field type, though. Just using the entry's `entry_date`.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer for another option with entry dates. If you don't know how to make the plugin, comment back here and I'll revise my answer later with a complete solution. Gotta run out the door right now though!

Comment: I think I can handle that!

Comment: I'm guessing I can use EE's existing date functions - is `parse_date_variables()` the one I should be working with?

Comment: You will want `format_date` since you are supplying your plugin with a UTC Unix timestamp. [https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/localization.html#Localize::format_date](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/localization.html#Localize::format_date)

Comment: See my answer below for full plugin code.

Answer (score 0):

Following Derek's advice above, I wrote a quick plugin to handle the conversion. Here's the plugin method code (note: I used the [EE Add-On Builder for Sublime Text](https://github.com/lukewilkins/EE-Add-On-Builder) to generate the plugin file and boilerplate code):

```
public function convert_timezone() {
    $timestamp = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('timestamp');
    $timezone = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('timezone');
    $format = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('format');

    return ee()->localize->format_date($format, $timestamp, $timezone);
}
```

And the tag it uses:

```
{exp:site_utilities:convert_timezone 
    timestamp='{entry_date}' 
    timezone='{events_tz}' 
    format='%g:%i%a %T'
 }
```

Comment: Nicely done! Thanks for sharing your complete solution.